# Is there an equivalent to optional chaining with arithmetic operators?

Tags: swift, option-type

I have two optional numbers that I add. Right now it looks like this:

```
if let a = optionalA {
    if let b = optionalB {
        return a + b
    }
}
return nil
```

For methods, there's the more convenient optional chaining syntax, like `optionalA.?method` syntax. Is there an equivalent for arithmetic operators that would return `nil` if either side was `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to create an operator `+?` that does just this like this:

```
infix func +?(a: Int?, b: Int?) -> Int? {
    if aa = a {
        if bb = b {
            return aa + bb
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

but I'm wondering if there's another, built-in way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is built in way. But you can make your own operator function:

```
func +(lhs: Int?, rhs: Int?) -> Int? {
    if let a = lhs {
        if let b = rhs {
            return a + b
        }
    }

    return nil
}

var a: Int? = 1
var b: Int? = 2

var c = a + b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the custom operator approach updated for Swift 3:

```
infix operator +?
func +?(a: Int?, b: Int?) -> Int? {
    if let aa = a, let bb = b {
        return aa + bb
    }
    return nil
}
```